# Can you make yourself like/hate something when you learned to hate/like it during early life?

Tags: learning

Suppose that someone develops liking (or even obsessing with) something since very early life, e.g watching football from age 5 to age 25. Is it possible to consciously make oneself hate it when one is older?

Can the converse happen also? Is it possible to hate something at a young age and then consciously make oneself like it when older?

If this "brain rewiring" can happen, what are the methods to achieve it? Is there any research on this subject?

Comment: This is a really broad question!  If you rewrite it to be a little more limited (choose either like->dislike or dislike-> like, etc), you might have more luck with answers.

Comment: thanks for your comment! yes, I may have had to confine my question to a more manageable chunk. Perhaps I may do so in the future in a new question post. Sorry, I'm new here I'm not sure if I can do that?

Comment: Yes it can definitly happen. I hated Shrimps and loved Videogames as a kid. Now i love Shrimps and hate Videogames :D

Comment: So do you want to know how one goes about reversing obsessions in clinical psychology?

Comment: I trieing to hate fishing because every time I have a chance to do it it gets screwed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of "loving" and "hating" happens on unconscious level or conscious but automatic level. Aaron T. Beck noticed that thoughts were not as unconscious as Freud had previously theorized and called them "automatic thoughts".
I don't see any reason for someone to start hating football but also you can get bored for watching it for 20 years.
 But you have techniques, exercises and therapies that can help you love yourself, start hate smoking or stop overeating for example.

[Cognitive behavioral therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy) (CBT) can be used for solving current problems and modifying dysfunctional (inaccurate and/or unhelpful) thinking and behavior.

Comment: As the wiki article you link to says in its opening paragraph, neurolinguistic programming is a largely discredited pseudoscience and is unlikely to belong in any scientific discussion.

Comment: Ok, it is, but I know person that stopped smoking after treatment. And in my humble opinion has set of good techniques that help people in many ways. So should I edit the answer and delete NLP? @Krysta

Comment: I'd recommend deleting the reference to NLP. It can be hard to determine a causal relationship with complicated behavioral changes (like stopping smoking), which is why rigorous experimental research is needed. Just because a technique seems to work occasionally doesn't mean that it actually works, in the sense that the outcomes are better than what you would get with no treatment.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer! So If I get it correct, there are techniques (i.e CBT) that can help one mitigate the effects of his faulty appetites but not outright change them, right? For example, if someone grows addicted to smoking from a young age, it can't be expected that he ever comes to dislike smoking when he indulges in it, but it can be expected that he learns to refrain from it right?

Comment: You are correct. CBT can only change how we interpret things in our thoughts but there is no certainty that it will affect our feelings and actions. CBT can help you but it's not 100% efficient method like any other. @burnedWood

Comment: @Krysta - That Wiki article is obviously biased.  I studied NLP for a while and cured myself of claustrophobia using it. I did it myself just by reading and using a paragraph from an NLP book. The medical profession in general, recognise the placebo effect. There is no scientific explanation for why placebo works for some people, but it just does.  My (simplistic) explanation of NLP is that it is a very sophisticated way of delivering a placebo. NLP won't cure a broken leg, but where psychosomatic disease exists then the cure can also be psychosomatic.